# Creating an elemental undead

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead

My character is a necromancer and in a turn of great fortune the party faced and killed a non-summoned [huge lightning elemental](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-lightning/huge-lightning-elemental/). As I asked in another [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156076/23058) there does not seem to be anything restricting a non-summoned elemental from becoming undead, but I am having some issues with a couple of the features. I am comparing the [skeleton](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/skeleton/), bloody, [zombie](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/zombie/), and fast zombie variants. I plan on using [Animate Dead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-dead/). The variants will be inside square brackets if they have a different value. I found converting the elemental to be surprisingly difficult and wanted to make sure that I didn't make any mistakes.

| ability | Original | Skeleton[Bloody] | Zombie[Fast] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Size | Huge | Same | Same |
| Type | outsider (air, elemental, extraplanar) | Undead (air, elemental, extraplanar) | Undead (air, elemental, extraplanar) |
| Alignment | Neutral | Evil | Evil |
| Initiative | +8 dex, +4 feat | +9 dex, + 4 feat | +7[9] dex |
| Senses | Darkvision 60 (outsider) | Darkvision 60 (undead) | Darkvision 60 (undead) |

I was unsure what subtypes were kept as the only example was giant is lost, but felt it kept all of its subtypes.

### DEFENSE

| ability | Original | Skeleton[Bloody] | Zombie[Fast] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC | (+8 Dex, +1 dodge, +2 natural, –2 size) |  |  |
| HP | 10d10+con-mod | 10d8+cha-mod | 14d8+cha-mod |
| Fort | +10 | 3 + 0[2] | 3 + 0 |
| Ref | +15 | 3+8 | 3+7[9] |
| Will | +5 | 5+0+2 | 5+0+2 |
| DR | DR 5/— | DR 5/bludgeoning | DR 5/slashing |
| Resistance/Immune | Immune:electricity | Immune:Cold |  |
| traits | elemental | elemental,undead | elemental,undead |

They lose their defensive abilities which is why the electricity immunity is lost, and that immunity didn't have any source listed. Losing the electricity immunity seems wrong.

### OFFENSE

| ability | Original | Skeleton[Bloody] | Zombie[Fast] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Speed | fly 100 | fly 100 | fly 100 |
| Melee | 2 slams +16 (2d6+5 plus 1d8 electricity) |  |  |
| Space and reach | both 15 | same | same |

The type and subtype do not state where the fly comes from, and it's not listed as magical or physical. If it's magical then it's fine, but if it's considered extraordinary it could be lost (unless you considering flying to improve its attack). For this I've considered the flight to be magical.

The electrical damage to its slam attack also does not have a listed source, but since it improves its attack I figured it should stay.

### STATISTICS

| ability | Original | Skeleton[Bloody] | Zombie[Fast] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Str | 20 | 20 | 22 |
| Dex | 27 | 29 | 25 |
| Con | 16 | NA | NA |
| Wis | 6 | 10 | 10 |
| Int | 11 | NA | NA |
| Cha | 11 | 10 | 10 |
| BAB | 10 | 7 | 10 |
| CMB | 17 | BAB+5 str + 2 size | BAB+6 str + 2 size |
| CMD | 36 | 10 base++7bab+5str+9+2size | 10base+7bab+6str+7[9]dex+2size |
| Feats | many | Improved Initiative | Toughness |
| Skills | many | None | None |
| Languages | Auran | NA | NA |

It's assumed that languages are lost due to no Int. Zombie BAB is higher because it has more HD.

### SPECIAL ABILITIES

Metal mastery - I believe this ability is kept because undead are allowed to keep any extraordinary abilities which improve their melee or ranged attacks.

Spark leap - same as above.

Final Questions:

- The elemental theme of the creature, does it lose the electrical immunity but keep the damage on the slam?
- Does it keep flying?

Comment: I feel like it's a stretch to say "does not seem to be anything restricting a non-summoned elemental from becoming undead" but I'll answer assuming your GM is deciding to allow it.

Comment: @Ifusaso I asked another question on it and those answers said that. DM's of course can always say No.

Comment: Isn't an elemental inhabiting a non-living body the definition of a construct?

Comment: @Carduus Arnt elementals themselves kindof non-living since they dont breath, eat, or sleep?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

- It loses its elemental damage and immunity (although not, strangely, its Metal Mastery/Spark Leap)

  - Some GM's may Rule 0 the Special Abilities off of it because they "don't make sense" or Rule 0 the elemental damage and immunity back because it "makes sense". I would definitely bring up all 4 before finalizing the creature's statblock for play.
- It may or may not have flight, depending on if your GM considers the Air subtype a "kind" subtype (it doesn't seem to be)

### Some of your presumptions are incorrect.

- It loses the [Elemental](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/Creature-types/#Elemental_Subtype) subtype; that is a "kind" of Outsider
- Flight is an effect of the [Air](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/Creature-types/#Air_Subtype) subtype, meaning the flight is natural

  - However, this seems to be retained unless your GM considers [Air] a "kind" (in which case it's lost)
- It loses the energy damage on its Slam because it is not a "[Special Quality](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98571/what-exactly-are-special-qualities)" to increase melee attack(s). If anything, it is a "Special Attack" because it is only listed in the Offense section of the statblock.

Also you didn't separate Fast Zombie statistics, so I figure I should make note

- Fast Zombie loses DR/slashing
- Gains 2 Dexterity instead of losing it

### Results (generated using Hero Lab then verified)

**Fast Zombie Elemental**
Fast huge lightning elemental zombie (Pathfinder RPG Bestiary 288, 289, Pathfinder RPG Bestiary 2 116)
NE Huge undead (air, extraplanar)
Init +9; Senses darkvision 60 ft.; Perception +0

**Defense**
AC 23, touch 17, flat-footed 14 (+9 Dex, +6 natural, -2 size)
hp 74 (14d8+14)
Fort +4, Ref +13, Will +9
Immune undead traits

**Offense**
Speed 10 ft., fly 100 ft. (clumsy)*
Melee slam +14 (2d6+9), 2 slams +14 (2d6+6)
Space 15 ft.; Reach 15 ft.
Special Attacks quick strikes

**Statistics**
Str 22, Dex 29, Con —, Int —, Wis 10, Cha 10
Base Atk +10.5; CMB +18; CMD 37
Feats Toughness[B]
Skills Acrobatics +9 (+1 to jump), Fly +13

**Special Abilities**
Darkvision (60 feet) You can see in the dark (black and white only).
Fly (100 feet, Clumsy) You can fly!*
Quick Strikes (Ex) Whenever a fast zombie takes a full-attack action, it can make one additional slam attack at its highest base attack bonus.
Metal Mastery (Ex) A lightning elemental gains a +3 bonus on attack rolls if its opponent is wearing metal armor, is wielding a metal weapon, or is made of metal (such as an iron golem).
Spark Leap (Ex) A lightning elemental gains a +10 bonus on bull rush, disarm, overrun, and trip attacks when it charges a creature against whom its metal mastery ability applies.

---

**Bloody Skeleton Elemental**
Bloody huge lightning elemental skeleton (Pathfinder RPG Bestiary 250, 251, Pathfinder RPG Bestiary 2 116)
NE Huge undead (air, extraplanar)
Init +13; Senses darkvision 60 ft.; Perception +0

**Defense**
AC 22, touch 17, flat-footed 13 (+9 Dex, +5 natural, -2 size)
hp 75 (10d8+20); fast healing 5
Fort +5, Ref +12, Will +7
Defensive Abilities channel resistance +4; DR 5/bludgeoning; Immune cold, undead traits

**Offense**
Speed 10 ft., fly 100 ft. (clumsy)*
Melee 2 claws +10 (1d8+5), 2 slams +10 (2d6+5)
Space 15 ft.; Reach 15 ft.

**Statistics**
Str 20, Dex 29, Con —, Int —, Wis 10, Cha 14
Base Atk +7.5; CMB +14; CMD 33
Feats Improved Initiative
Skills Fly +5
SQ deathless

**Special Abilities**
Channel Resistance +4 +4 bonus to save vs. Channel Energy.
Damage Reduction (5/bludgeoning) You have Damage Reduction against all except Bludgeoning attacks.
Darkvision (60 feet) You can see in the dark (black and white only).
Deathless (Su) Return to unlife 1 hour after being destroyed.
Fast Healing 5 (Ex) Heal damage every round unless you are killed.
Fly (100 feet, Clumsy) You can fly!*
Immunity to Cold You are immune to cold damage.
Metal Mastery (Ex) A lightning elemental gains a +3 bonus on attack rolls if its opponent is wearing metal armor, is wielding a metal weapon, or is made of metal (such as an iron golem).
Spark Leap (Ex) A lightning elemental gains a +10 bonus on bull rush, disarm, overrun, and trip attacks when it charges a creature against whom its metal mastery ability applies.

Comment: Why does it keep the languages?

Comment: It doesn't that was a typo (fixed). Oddly the templates doesn't say that you lose Languages, but Intelligence specifies that you must have at least 3 intelligence to understand a language, so you were right on that point.